# Apache POI-HSSF vs POI-XSSF

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

> HSSF is the POI Project's pure Java implementation of the Excel '97(-2007) file format. XSSF is the POI Project's pure Java implementation of the Excel 2007 OOXML (.xlsx) file format.

Are there any ***export*** limitations when using HSSF?

I've once read somewhere that Excel '97 just supported `<65.000 Entries`.

Is it safe to use HSSF to export excel sheets with more than 65.000 Entries, or why would I use XSSF?

Comment: 65536 is an excel 97 to 2003 limit, so you can't have xls files with more than 65536 rows. Hence HSSF will work just fine with **xls** files, as the limit is xls and not HSSF. **xlsx** files support up to 1M+ rows, and XSSF will handle them correctly.

Comment: Ah the edit makes it clearer. so for no misunderstanding, you recommend me to take XSSF to support more Entries without data loss? @BackSlash

Comment: Yes, use xlsx. xls doesn't support more than 65536 entries.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://superuser.com/a/366473/206417) Excel 97 to 2003 supports a maximum of 65,536 rows. So no, with HSSF you won't be able to store more than 65536 entries. However you can do it with XLSX (Excel 2007+) which can handle up to 1,048,576 rows and can be saved using **X**SSF. It won't be compatible with Excel 97/2003 though.