# Mapping of Apache POI HSSF/XSSF to XLS/XLSX

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xlsx, xls

Apache POI 4.x here. I see there are two types of `Workbook` implementations:

- **HSSF Workbook**
- **XSSF Workbook**

I need to write a Java 8 app that reads Excel sheets with either "`.xls`" (XLS) or "`.xlsx`" (XLSX) extensions. Meaning, Excel files that were saved in the "old" (pre 2003) format, or the newer one.

Is it safe to assume I use HSSF for XLS files, and XSSF for XLSX files? Or is the mapping logic a little bit more complicated there? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45936450/5235665) seems to indicate I'm correct, but that doesn't leave me feeling totally sure that I understand the mapping and "when to use" logic of HSSF vs XSSF.

I've scoured the POI documentation but can't find a clear answer for the life of me.

Comment: Why not just use `WorkbookFactory` + `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel` and let Apache POI figure out the type for you?

Comment: Probably because I didn't know it existed! Thanks @Gagravarr (+1)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HSSF (`org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel` package) is for XLS files format

XSSF (`org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel` package) is for XLSX files format (newer one)

Model classes from both packages (xssf and hssf) implements common interfaces from `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel` package. So, you potentially can write a code using  `ss` package and it will work with abstractions over xssf or hssf.