# Write and Past on CSV - Selenium , Python

Tags: python, selenium, csv, copy, paste

How do I paste an element into a column of the csv file? The copied item is a piece of text in the browser (and I succeed with CTRL + C). however i would like to figure it out how to paste it. Thank you

Comment: It is funny, You need to use for e.g. apache poi. Create file (or open existing), find sheet, find row, find cell and add values in it. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65940340/how-to-update-an-excel-file-in-java

Comment: Thanks!!  I'll try the guide of VInceLomba, right? because i Use python...

Comment: @Gaj Julije It also works for python ?

Comment: Not sure, python has it own libraries. see https://wiki.python.org/jython/PoiExample